# Переход по папкам, в файловом менеджере, методом GET

Tags: php

Как сделать, что бы переход по папкам, был с помощью метода GET? Я никак понять не могу.

```
<?php error_reporting(-1);
header('Content-Type: text/html; char set=utf-8');
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$img = 'papka.jpg';
$img2 = 'file.jpg';
$img3 = 'img.jpg';

$dir = __DIR__;

$files = scandir($dir);

echo '<ul style="padding: 0">';
foreach ($files as $f) {
    echo '<li style="list-style: none;">';

   if(pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'txt'){
        echo '<img src="' . $img2 . '">';
        echo '<span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding-left: 3px;">' . $f .'</span>';
   }
    elseif(pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'jpg'){
        echo '<img src="' . $img3 . '">';
        echo '<span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding-left: 3px;">' . $f .'</span>';
   }

   elseif(is_dir($dir . '/' . $f)){
        echo '<a href="?papka=' . $f . '">';

        echo '<img src="' . $img . '">';
        echo '<span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding-left: 3px;">' . $f . '</span>';

        echo '</a>';
   }

   echo '</li>';
}

 echo '</ul>';

?>
```

Comment: И что у Вас не получается?

Comment: сделать переход по папкам

Answer (score 1):

Замените

> `$dir = __DIR__`;

на

```
$dir = __DIR__;
if (isset($_GET['papka']) {
  $curDir = $_GET['papka'];
  $dir += $curDir;
  $curDir += '/'
} else
  $curDir = '';
```

И вот это

> `echo '<a href="?papka=' . $f . '">';`

Замените на

```
printf('<a href="%s?papka=%s%s">', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $curDir, $f);
```

Comment: А почему такое не работает?

Comment: <!-- language: lang-php -->
<?php
$scan = __DIR__;
$dir = scandir($scan);
echo '<pre>';
print_r ($dir);
echo '</pre>';
?>
<ol>
    <?foreach($dir as $v):?>
        <?if(is_dir($scan.'/'.$v)):?>
        <?php $l = isset($link) ? $link .'/' .$v :$v; ?>
        <li id="dir"><a href="fm.php?page=program&link=<?=$l?>"><?=$v?></a></li>
        <?else:?>
        <li id='file'><?=$v?></li>
        <?endif?>
    <?endforeach?>
</ol>

Comment: @DivMan Как минимум потому, что Вы всегда сканируете один и тот же каталог `$scan = __DIR__; $dir = scandir($scan)`

Comment: не работает    >$dir = __DIR__;
if (isset($_GET['papka'])) {
  $curDir = $_GET['papka'];
  $dir += $curDir;
  $curDir += '/';
} 
else{
  $curDir = '';
 }

Comment: Как вы вставляете php? почему нигде не пишут про это? И почему админы не добавят кнопки?

Comment: @DivMan Не работает что? Какие кнопки Вам нужно добавить, если Вам влом почитать справку? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting